# how to catch edited cells range with onEdit(e) trigger when filter applied

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, eventtrigger

Imagine we have a sheet with a table and with filter applied (see linked example https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wPE3bufOyWt9MdB6yt7HK9d1AB5GbzGcXx0GIf-M4nA/edit#gid=0).
I have filtered rows in column A by selecting only one category "Field-1".
Next I want to edit cells in columns B, C, D as bulk one step edit by doing:

- Ctrl+C of data from B2:D2
- Ctrl+V to cells in columns B, C, D for all rows filtered by "Field-1".

With onEdit(e) I expect to catch the range of edited cells, but in fact my range is partitioned into subranges by hidden rows so getA1Notation() generates one row only as a result: B4:D4 in our example (see Logger.log outputs). It does not catch other rows (B6:D6, B8:D8, B10:D10).

Is there a way to obtain the list of all cells affected by such bulk edit operation or at least first and last row of affected range?

Comment: onEdit trigger only fires on user edits

Comment: sure and that user performs bulk edit on filtered range, however onEdit does not catch all cells affected by this edit operation

Comment: Please explain bulk edit

Comment: If by bulk edit you mean the user executes a script that performs an edit then yes the on Edit trigger will not respond to edits by another script

Comment: I reread your question I guess your bulk edit is a paste.  You can capture a paste and and execute a loop to capture the entire edit by utilizing event objects rowStart, rowEnd, columnStart, columnEnd but of course oldValue is not available for anything but the upperleft corner.

Comment: Take a look and the event object with `Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));`

Comment: [Here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68201788/7215091)

Comment: Trigger onEdit works perfectly when filter is not applied means if I paste over B4:D10, both getA1Notation() or Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e)); show the correct range - B4:D10. But if I apply filter on the page and I have visible rows 4, 6, 8 and 10 (for example), and then after pasting values over all these visible rows (4,6,8,10) the trigger reports that I have performed changes in row 2 only (D2:D4 or "range":{"columnEnd":4,"columnStart":2,"rowEnd":4,"rowStart":4}). So existence of active filter and hidden rows between impacted rows affects the trigger's behavior.

Comment: I'm not surprised because apps script has problems with array formulas as well.  Personally, I never used formulas or any of the spreadsheets special tools.  I do everything I want in scripting.